# instant run not working and always restarting the whole app - android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

What I have tried:

1. I have disabled, enabled the instant run multiple times.
2. I have tested the instant run on many projects.
3. I tried Invalidate Caches and Restart.
4. I tried to change on XML only, Java only, static fields, variables. all the cases restarts the whole app.

Still the instant run button [image: Instant Run Button Image] restarts the app always.

The devices i use for testing are

Motorolla Moto G4 Android 6.0.1 and Samsung Galaxy s4 Android 5.1

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Can you share with us what is the os version of emulator/device you are working with?

Comment: @BozicNebojsa I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Seems like There's a bug in Android Studio 2.3(24Feb2017 Build)
I have Workaround for Instant Run.
Working for me:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

Not Working for me:(>2.3.0)

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

So You could try **2.3.0** for Project-level build.gradle

Welcome to #AndroidDev :)X)

Comment: Worked for me,Great!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time since the question but I find myself in the same problem and I just discovered the solution:

In Gradle (Module: app)

```
buildTypes {
   ...
     debug {   multiDexEnabled true  }

}
```

The mutidex was enabled in debug mode this was causing in my case the failure in instantrun at android studio 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Just a little hint. When I switched from Android Studio 1.5 to 2.0 (stable) the new Instant Run didn't work with layout changes. I tried Run > Clean and rerun app and I solved, since that moment Instant Run works.And please refer below link.I hope it will help you out

[Android Studio 2.0: Why does Instant Run not work when modifying xml layout resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902467/android-studio-2-0-why-does-instant-run-not-work-when-modifying-xml-layout-reso)

or you can further refer below link for configuration

[Android Studio 2.0 Instant Run Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980145/android-studio-2-0-instant-run-not-working)

Comment: It was working till Android studio 2.2. on the new updated things went wrong

Comment: so you press play button (a little green icon) always to build the project? If yes then don't do that for instant run press button which is between play button and debug button. Further information can be found in below link as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFyKclKBGf0

Answer (score 1):

I also had a same problem after update "Android Studio 2.3"
 
Even small xml change went full install.

message : "Instant Run applied code changes and restarted the app. Static Initializer Change"

So I started to find which one made this problem from libraries I use.

and when I remove realm dependency from my code, Instant run work properly.

hmm. It's not a perfect solution. but this might be a clue.

ps - removing dependency is little bit annoying. so first time I removed realm initialize code but it is not working. only remove all realm dependency will work...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For running the app its Shift+F10 for applying changes its Ctrl+F10. Try it. Hope it works.